# Allow a user in JawsDB to make an INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, database, heroku

I have a deployed app in Heroku and the DB manager is MySQL JawsDB.
I would like to use Navicat to insert data for my users. The app is just for consultation. 
I can connect to my JawsDB DB but, when I'm trying to insert new data I get an error `1142 - INSERT command denied to user 'myJawsDBUser'@'myIPAddress' for table 'myTable'`.
I checked documentation and says:

> If you are on one of JawsDB’s shared plans, you may have breached the database size allotted via your plan. When a database grows larger than the plan allows, INSERT privileges are revoked on the database user until the database is brought back into compliance.

After make a check of the size of my DB, I see that I have less than maximum size plan allows.I think is a problem with privileges, how can I change this if I don't have access to Users table

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disclosure before answer: I'm with JawsDB :)

Jaws calculates used space by adding up the data_length and index_length values of each table in that database according to the information_schema.

A query like the one below is used to do this.

```
select
    s.schema_name
    ,sp.grantee user
    ,cast(round(sum(coalesce(t.data_length + t.index_length, 0)) / 1024 / 1024, 3) as char) db_size_mb
    ,sp.has_insert
from
    information_schema.schemata s
    inner join
    information_schema.tables t on s.schema_name = t.table_schema
    inner join (
        select
            spi.grantee
            ,spi.table_schema
            ,max(
                case
                    when spi.privilege_type = 'INSERT' then 1
                    else 0
                end
            ) has_insert
        from
            information_schema.schema_privileges spi
        group by
            spi.grantee
            ,spi.table_schema
    ) sp on s.schema_name = sp.table_schema
group by
    s.schema_name;
```

If the size of the database's tables exceeds the size granted to the user's plan, the INSERT privilege is temporarily revoked until database size is brought back into compliance with the plan. This can either be done by deleting old data or by upgrading their plan.

Comment: I finally found this answer after I spent half of my day on why I could not access my JawsDB on Heroku. The problem was that I have exceeded the size limit but there was no indication on Heroku and JawsDB that this was the problem. The logs on Heroku did not show anything relevant to it but a MySQL error. There is a FAQ on Heroku JawsDB which is related to it but it is for some reason under the section of Node.js.

Comment: Personally, i would really like to receive an indication that this a size limit problem of the db and not simply receive a general MySQL error. Or at least the docs on Heroku or/and JawsDB should highlight in a very apparent way this size limitation.

Comment: Great answer, but I agree that it's a bit frustrating to shut off insert access without any notice to the user.

Comment: please please please - highlight this on the JawsDB info page - I spent like 3 hours trying to guess why my app doesn't have INSERT permission.

Comment: just spent 2 hours with same error - jawsDB REALLY needs to give some indication that the error is caused by size limit!!! Wastes developer time!

Comment: This is absurd, not only did I waste an entire week troubleshooting this since it's just a hobby project, but now I have literally no way to get *under* that 5MB limit. All my stuff is just trapped now. Just deleting old data doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove some data if you want to get back below the allowed size limit.

To get an idea of what tables are taking a lot of space:

```sql
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' ORDER BY data_length DESC
```

Once unnecessary data has been removed from a table, you need to recompute the table size. `ANALYZE TABLE table_name` and `OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name` cannot be used since you do not have insert right, but one trick is to update the table engine (with the same value).

For instance, if your tables are using `InnoDB`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: Are there any other tricks other than the altering the table Engine? Unfortunately it's not working for me - I cleared a table which should bring me under but it's just not working.

Comment: Welp, I discovered that since ALTERing the TABLE ENGINE doesn't work - I just would DROP the table and re-create it.